# Shopify - How to change background color of a title on collection page by the product tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

what I'm trying to do is change the background color of a title area in my collection page thats only including "Bespoke" tag. The following code changes the all of the products background even those products don't have a "Bespoke" tag.

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if product.tags contains 'Bespoke' %}
    <style>
      .title {
        background-color: green !important;
      }
    </style>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi why don't you try to add class based on the product tag then style those classes

Comment: I don't think I'm able to add class to the specific products. If so can you please help me through?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Im using DAWN theme**

Add this code in the collection list class as shown in image then this class shows in main product div and you can style based on this class.

```
{% if product.tags contains 'Bespoke' %} Bespoke{% endif %}
```

Comment: I did try this but I believe I'm making a mistake is it okay if i mail you?

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: if you are using DAWN theme then you need to add this code in   -- main-collection-product-grid.liquid --- file

Comment: I'm using "Showcase" theme

Comment: i need to check the files first for this theme.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your effort.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252023/discussion-between-mbkadoglu-and-jaswinder-kaur).